# error while converting json array to csv using perl

Tags: arrays, json, perl, csv

im using a perl script to convert from JSON to csv. the sampple json is like this,

```
[{"id":100,
"primary-codes":["E0181V00","E0226V00"],
"substitute-codes":["E0181D00","E0226100"],
"fk-id":2294}]
```

and the perl code i used to convert this to csv is,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use utf8;
use warnings;
use strict;
use lib '.';
use JSON::PP qw(decode_json);

my $json;
{
local $/;
open my $fh, '<', 'output_array.json' or die $!;
$json = <$fh>;
}

my $perl = decode_json $json;
my $filename = 'sample.csv';
open(my $fh, '>>:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
say $fh 'nk_id,prim_cd,sub_cd,fk_id';

for (@$perl){
my $nk_id = '"' . $_->{"id"} . '"';
my $prim_cd= '"' . $_->{"primary-codes"} . '"';                
my $sub_cd= '"' . $_->{"substitute-codes"} . '"'; 
my $fk_id= '"' . $_->{"fk-id"} . '"';                                  

say $fh "$nk_id," . "$prim_cd," . "$sub_cd," . "$fk_id";
}
close $fh;
```

The output i get is like this,

```
nk_id,prim_cd,sub_cd,fk_id
100,ARRAY(0x201549f8),ARRAY(0x20154a88),2294
```

but i want it to be,

```
100,"E0181V00,E0226V00","E0181D00,E0226100",2294
```

i tried using ,

```
my $prim_cd = '"' . join ",", @{ $perl->[0]{"primary-codes"} } . '"';
```

But it just returns the count and not the elements.

Please help me out with this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: im pretty new to shell scripting and have absolute zero knowledge in PERL, kindly help me out or guide me in the right direction to achieve this.

Comment: How did you put all this together with "zero knowledge" of Perl? This is pretty good, and your attempt is right on.

Comment: tweaking code from the web.

Comment: Well, a good job :).  You were right on (to seek an array because of that 2), and as you can see in my answer only that precedence foiled it. I hope that further comments are of some use as well

Comment: Thanks! I actually spent close to a week trying to make it work. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one detail that subverted your honest attempt is the precedence.  In

```
my $prim_cd = '"' . join ",", @{ $perl->[0]{"primary-codes"} } . '"';
```

the list `@{ $perl->[0]...}` is first concatenated (`.`) with `"`, and as the `.` operator imposes scalar context the number of elements in the list is used, yielding `2"`. Only then does `join` do its thing, "joining" the given list (which is a single element, `2"`)

Just add parenthesis

```
for (@$perl){
    my $nk_id   = '"' . $_->{"id"} . '"';
    my $prim_cd = '"' . join(',', @{$_->{'primary-codes'}}) . '"';
    my $sub_cd  = '"' . join(',', @{$_->{'substitute-codes'}}) . '"'; 
    my $fk_id   = '"' . $_->{"fk-id"} . '"'; 
    say $fh "$nk_id,$prim_cd,$sub_cd,$fk_id";
}
```

A few notes.

- You forgot `use feature qw(say);` without which `say` won't work.
- What is shown has no use of `use utf8;`, which is about the source file itself
- What is shown doesn't need `use lib`; that specifies paths to be searched for modules. (It won't help in finding files, if that was the idea.).  However, once we are at it ...
- I avoid using `.` as it can create problems ranging from confusion to direct errors. For one, do you mean the current working directory, or the directory of the script? They aren't the same. Assuming that you use it for the script's directory (which it isn't), replace it with

  ```
  use FindBin qw($RealBin);
  use lib $RealBin;
  ```
- To slurp a file you can also do

  ```
  my $json = do {
      local $/;
      open my $fh, '<', 'output_array.json' or die $!;
      <$fh>;
  };
  ```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I implemented ur suggestion. And it works! However I'm getting this error while "" appears inside the substitute-codes element: Can't use string ("") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs". went through a lot of material, but none seem to address the issue from this perspective.

Comment: if( $_->{"substitute-codes"} eq "") { my $sub_cd = '"' . $_->{"substitute-codes"} . '"' ;} else { my $sub_cd = '"' . join(',', @{$_->{'substitute-codes'}}) . '"' ;} I tried this, but am getting: Global symbol "$sub_cd" requires explicit package name

Comment: I used shell script to pre process the file used in perl script. I used
line 1 : perl -pi -w -e 's/"substitute-codes":""/"substitute-codes":["0"]/g;' output_array.json
line 2 :perl -pi -w -e 's/"primary-codes":""/"primary-codes":["0"]/g;' output_array.json
This fixed the issue.. Yay!

Comment: @Sultan Great :).  The error you quote means that `$_->{'primary-codes'}` does not return an arrayref at all, which is what `@{ }` needs. So the `"substitute-codes"` in JSON may not be an array? Then you'd indeed be best served by a bit of code to decide that (instead of cramming it inline). The builtin [ref](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) can tell, for instance: `my $r = ref $_->{'primary-codes'}; if (not $r) { #just a string, not reference at all, no need for @{} } elsif ($r eq 'ARRAYREF') { # ok, do the @{...} } else { # oups, unexpected? }`